# MySQL query audit log w/ metrics

Tags: mysql, mariadb, audit, audit-logging

My company has a very specific need to audit queries run against the DB, more specifically DML statements less selects. Ideally we want retrieve the specific metrics

- Who ran the query
- When was the query run
- What was the query
- Table(s) affected by the query (can probably be parsed out of the query itself)
- How many rows were affected by the query (consultants won't budge on this)

I've tried the general log, the slow log and the mariadb audit plugin with no avail. Are there any solutions out there aside from table trigger that I can explore?

We would like to export the logs if possible for outside parsing, however this is not a hard requirement.

Comment: this all seems more suited to the application layer than the database layer.  do you really have different database users for different end users, for instance?

Comment: @ysth I agree with you, it should theoretically be handled on the application layer. However, I suppose the consultants want to protect against a rogue entity that goes into the db and drops a table for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Percona Server is a branch of MySQL that supports more detail in the slow query log, including rows affected. See examples in this documentation page: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/8.0/diagnostics/slow_extended.html

That would give you the who, when, what, and `rows_affected`.

The tables affected can be extracted from each log event using some options of [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html), a tool included in the free Percona Toolkit. You could also use filter options of this tool to limit the results to DML statements.

Percona Server is also needed if you want to log statements run inside stored procedures (see the option `log_slow_sp_statements` on the page I linked to above).

However, none of the solutions logs statements run inside triggers. So if you want to make your audit complete, you must prohibit use of database triggers in your organization.

You tagged your question [mariadb](/questions/tagged/mariadb). I don't know if MariaDB supports the same extensions to the slow-query log, you'll have to research that in the MariaDB documentation.

Comment: Hi Bill, unfortunately I am unable to switch flavors of MySQL. We're running RDS instances of MySQL.

Comment: Okay, understood. Well, you give up a lot of control when you use RDS. You may not be able to continue that if you have such specific auditing requirements.